# CakePHP 2.3: Conditionally retrieve unique model information based on another model's use of it

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to create an AJAX form whereby the content of a select field populates based on the choice of a preceding select field (you see this a lot with 'country' populating 'state/province'). In my case, I want users to be able to choose their `province` only if active `accounts` exist in it.

The Javascript I can write no problem. Fetching the data is where I'm... not so much stuck as doing too much work. CakePHP likes to build select fields with options in an array of the form

`$options = array(select_option_value => display_text)`

My strategy, though functional, *must* be more convoluted than cake intended (this a is segment of a controller method).

```
$provinceData = $this->Account->find('all',array('recursive' => 0,
                                                      'joins' => array(
                                                                      array(
                                                                        'table' => 'provinces',
                                                                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                                                                        'conditions' => array('Account.province_id = provinces.id')
                                                                      )),
                                                       'fields'=>array('provinces.id', 'provinces.name', 'provinces.abbrev'),
                                                       'conditions' => array('registration > 2')));
$provinces = array();
foreach($provinceData as $pd) {
    /*note: lowercase, plural below b/c can't get 'alias' => 'Province' 
      to work in joins array above : ( */
    $id = $pd['provinces']['id'];
    $name = $pd['provinces']['name'];
    $provinces[$id] = $name;
}
$this->set(compact('provinces'));
```

Can anyone point out a more appropriate way to do this? I assume there must be a MySQL query that can do this, but I'm pretty bad at writing elaborate MySQL queries in the first place, let alone via Cake's convention (and, for you MySQL gurus out there, I'm happy to do this from a `Model->query(//MySQL code)` call instead!

Any and all help truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the relationship `Account` belongsTo `Province` you can try this code:

```
$accounts = $this->Account->find(
    'all', 
    array(
      'fields' => array('Account.province_id', 'Province.name'),
      'conditions' => array('Account.registration > 2'),
      'group' => 'Account.province_id'
   )
);

$provinces = Hash::combine($accounts, '{n}.Account.province_id', '{n}.Province.name');

$this->set(compact('provinces'));
```

edit: missed bracket and a period instead of an underscore . Now should work

Comment: Yep! Two small edits, in case anyone else wishes to model  your solution for their own; should read '{n}.Account.province_id' and you're shy a paren on the `Account->find()` call.

Also, I've seen this syntax: `{n}.....` more than once—is this a Cake convention, or a facet of PHP I'm not familiar with? Where does one learn about it?

Comment: I edited. Sorry for the typos. For the hash syntax see [CakePHP manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#hash-path-syntax)